# AngularJs directives: Copied code verbatim from official tutorial and it doesn't work. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The official tutorial is from here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

I copied the official code from "Creating Directives", sub-header "Template-expanding directive". Example 1 works perfectly (the example where there are only `script.js` and `index.html`), with my browser rendering the desired results. Example 2 is a simple expansion of Example 1, replacing the "template" line from the directive file with a "templateUrl" line, and adding a `my-customer.html` file as the template. However, this doesn't work for me.

The copied code are as follows. All files are put in the same folder:

1. index3.html:

   ```
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Example - example-example12-production</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js">      </script>
       <script src="script3.js"></script>   
   </head>
   <body ng-app="docsTemplateUrlDirective">
       <div ng-controller="Controller">
       <div my-customer></div>
       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. script3.js:

   ```
   angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
   .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.customer = {
            name: 'Naomi',
            address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
       };
    }])
   .directive('myCustomer', function() {
       return {
           templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
       };
   });
   ```
3. my-customer.html:

`Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}`

Why do I get a blank page when I open `index3.html` in my browser?

Comment: you add this code??                                                                                  <div ng-controller="Controller">
  <div my-customer></div>
</div>

Comment: I don't understand your question. I didn't add this code myself; it's copied from the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by disabling cache when developer tool is on (option chosen in the js console preferences of Chrome). The code was correct. It wasn't rendered correctly because of cache.

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body ng-app="docsTemplateUrlDirective">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <div my-customer></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

my-customer.html

```
Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}
```

script.js

```
var app=angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', []);

app.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
        name: 'Naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };
}]);

app.directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
    };
});
```

above code fine work in my pc....

Comment: All file are same directory

Comment: I think maybe my http server has an issue. I'd update the code. Then I refresh the page in the browser, and then nothing happens. I try this a few times, closing the pages, restarting the server, removing an innocuous blank line in the code file, and then boom it works. It's hard to know if one's code is correct, if one cannot rely on the feedback given by the browser. Do you happen to know why that would be the case?

Comment: Fixed it. By disabling cache when developer tool is on.